# Tem como usar campos e botões comuns do HTML com JSF?

Tags: html, jsf

Estou fazendo um projeto com JSF e também estou usando campos e botões comuns do HTML em alguns formulários.

**Trecho do meu (X)HTML**

```html
<div class="clearfix">
 <input class="small DDD" type="tel" placeholder="DDD"
 maxlength="2" name="DDD" id="DDDFb"
 onkeypress="return onlyNumbersValue(event);" /> 
  <input class="medium telefoneFb" type="tel" maxlength="9"
 placeholder="Digite seu Telefone" name="fone" id="phoneFb"
 onkeypress="return onlyNumbersValue(event);"></input> 
  <input type="hidden" id="fb_phoneId" name="phoneId" />
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" id="cadastrarTel" />
```

Quero saber como pegar o valor que o usuário digitou e enviar para o meu SetCampo no JSF sem precisar usar o `<h:inputText value="#{meuBean.contato.ddd}">` e `<h:commandButton action="#{meuBean.cadastrar}" value="Cadastrar">`.

Comment: Por que não usa o JSF mesmo? É por causa da aparência?

Comment: Sim, pela aparência e porque eu tive dificuldades de pegar dados do JavaScript e passar para campos do JSF. com HTML puro funciona sem dificuldades.